# How to get correct answer

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have this example, how i can make it to show the correct answer.
If everyone is online, then the global status is online.
If some one is away, global status is away.
If everyone is offline -> offline.

```
var group, part1, part2, part3;

group = 'Group Status';
part1 = 'online';
part2 = 'away';
part3 = 'offline';

if( part1 === 'online' || part2 === 'online' || part3 === 'online' ){
    group = 'Online';
    console.log('All users are online. Group status: ' + group);
}else if( part1 === 'away' || part2 === 'away' || part3 === 'away' ){
    group = 'Away';
    console.log('One of the users is away. Group status: ' + group);
}else if( part1 === 'offline' || part2 === 'offline' || part3 === 'offline' ){
    group = 'Offline';
    console.log('One of the users is offline. Group status: ' + group);
}else{
    group = 'Not found';
    console.log('Status not found. Group status: ' + group);
}
```

Answer: the priority of this code is Online > Away > Offline.

I replaced and it worked as i want: Offline > Away > Online.

```
var group, part1, part2, part3;
group = 'Group Status';
part1 = 'online';
part2 = 'away';
part3 = 'away';


if( part1 === 'offline' || part2 === 'offline' || part3 === 'offline' ){
    group = 'Offline';
    console.log('One of the users is offline. Group status: ' + group);
}else if( part1 === 'away' || part2 === 'away' || part3 === 'away' ){
    group = 'Away';
    console.log('One of the users is away. Group status: ' + group);
}else if( part1 === 'online' || part2 === 'online' || part3 === 'online' ){
    group = 'Online';
    console.log('All users are online. Group status: ' + group);
}else{
    group = 'Not found';
    console.log('Status not found. Group status: ' + group);
}
```

Comment: In the first if you're checking if some one is `green` not `online`

Comment: Hi Carlos. True, edited the question.

Comment: So what is the prioritization? If some one is online, regardless of other condition, group status should be online. And the group status would be away, only if the others parts should be either away or offline. Is that correct?

Comment: Your conditions exclude each other. *s.o. is online* and *s.o. is away* can be true at the same time. Do you mean *everybody is online* for your first condition?

Comment: Hi Vikash. Correct. If all are online, status is online. If anyone is away, status changes to away, if anyone is offline, status changes to offline. Priority: offline > away > online

Comment: @Eugene Then why does both the text and the code of your question say something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could move all parts into an array and check with [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) for the wanted status.

```js
var group = 'Group Status',
    parts = ['online', 'away', 'offline'];

if (parts.some(function (a) { return a === 'offline'; })) {
    group = 'Offline';
    console.log('One of the users is offline. Group status: ' + group);
} else if (parts.some(function (a) { return a === 'away'; })) {
    group = 'Away';
    console.log('One of the users is away. Group status: ' + group);
} else if (parts.every(function (a) { return a === 'online'; })) {
    group = 'Online';
    console.log('All users are online. Group status: ' + group);
} else {
    group = 'Not found';
    console.log('Status not found. Group status: ' + group);
}
```

ES6

```js
var group = 'Group Status',
    parts = ['online', 'away', 'offline'],
    check = string => item => item === string;

if (parts.some(check('offline'))) {
    group = 'Offline';
    console.log('One of the users is offline. Group status: ' + group);
} else if (parts.some(check('away'))) {
    group = 'Away';
    console.log('One of the users is away. Group status: ' + group);
} else if (parts.every(check('online'))) {
    group = 'Online';
    console.log('All users are online. Group status: ' + group);
} else {
    group = 'Not found';
    console.log('Status not found. Group status: ' + group);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I think you want to do: http://es6fiddle.net/itfgy2xt/

It helps to use an array for your group parts, so you can use array methods, namely [`Array.prototype.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and [`Array.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf). Note that `every` is IE9+.

`every` returns `true` only if the function for every element returns `true`, and `indexOf` returns the index of the element in the array or `-1` if the element can't be found.

```
var groupStatus  = 'Group Status',
    parts = [];

parts[0] = 'online';
parts[1] = 'away';
parts[2] = 'offline';

// check if everyone is online
if (parts.every(function (el) { return el === 'online'; })) {
    groupStatus = 'Online';
}
// check if at least someone is online or away
else if (parts.indexOf('online') >= 0 || parts.indexOf('away') >= 0) {
    groupStatus = 'away';
}
else {
    groupStatus = 'offline';
}

console.log('Group status: ' + groupStatus);
```

Comment: Thank you for your example!